# Guest OS install from Physical CD/DVD Hyper-v 2012 R2

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have been looking around if it's possible to install a Guest OS on Hyper-V 2012 R2 Using the physical CD/DVD drive. The only ways i see to install guest OS is by mounting an ISO. Is hyper-v able to access the Host physical CD/DVD at all?

Same behavior on Hyper-V Windows 8.1 pro .

Am I missing something or ISO is the only way to go?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Windows Server 2012 R2 & Windows 8.1

It turns out that Second Generation Hyper-V doesn't include the option to boot from physical CD/DVD. Only Generation one Have the option to boot from it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282285.aspx

*In previous versions of Hyper-V there was only one type of virtual machine. Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012 R2 includes two types of virtual machine generations that can be selected when you create a new virtual machine.

Generation 1   Provides the same virtual hardware to the virtual machine as in previous versions of Hyper-V.

Generation 2   Provides the following new functionality on a virtual machine:

- Secure Boot (enabled by default)
- Boot from a SCSI virtual hard disk
- Boot from a SCSI **virtual DVD**
- PXE boot by using a standard network adapter
- UEFI firmware support*

### Windows Server 2012 & Windows 8

See [This](https://serverfault.com/a/565001/74549) answer

Answer (score 7):

You can connect the host physical CD/DVD drive to the VM while creating the VM and any time afterward.

```
New VM
```

[image]

```
Existing VM
```

[image]

Comment: I dont have that option - Im running  Windows Server 2012 R2. I'll update my post with some screenshots.

Comment: I see. You must be using/creating Generation 2 VM's. If you select Generation 1 as the VM hardware type then the settings in my answer are available.

Answer (score 0):

In Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 you can do it from PS:

Set-VmDvdDrive -Name VirtualServerName -path D:

Replace D with the drive letter of your physical drive.

also try these power-shell samples in [Tech Net Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848470.aspx#feedback) page

Comment: It didn't work for me at all initially. I took out -Name and then it seemed to work, but I couldn't find the disk, so I added a DVD with no media in hyper-V Manager. Then I ran the command again, and it gave the error Physical DVD drives are not supported on SCSI controllers, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: get names of virtual machine by this powershell command : Get-VM | Where { $_.State –eq ‘Running’ }    but why this is not working...